# Swift, php - can't upload image

Tags: php, ios, swift

I'm trying to upload an image to my web server from an ios app using PHP. I have the following code that manages the upload:

```
func uploadImage()
    {
        // get userId from saved credentials
        let userId = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "userId")

        let param = ["userId":userId]

        let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(profPicIV.image!, 1)

        if(imageData == nil )  { return }

        self.imgUploadButton.isEnabled = false

        let uploadScriptUrl = URL(string: "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/scripts/imageUpload.php")

        let boundary = generateBoundaryString()

        var request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: uploadScriptUrl!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        request.httpBody = createBodyWithParameters(param as! [String : String], filePathKey: "file", imageDataKey: imageData!, boundary: boundary)

        request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        if (profPicIV.image == nil)
        {
            return
        }


        if(imageData == nil)
        {
            return
        }

        let session = URLSession.shared


        let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {
            (
            data, response, error) in

            guard ((data) != nil), let _:URLResponse = response, error == nil else {
                print("error")
                return
            }

            if let dataString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
            {
                print(dataString)
            }

        })


        task.resume()


    }
```

along with the createBodyWithParameters:

```
func createBodyWithParameters(_ parameters: [String: String]?, filePathKey: String?, imageDataKey: Data, boundary: String) -> Data {
        let body = NSMutableData();

        if parameters != nil {
            for (key, value) in parameters! {
                body.appendString("--\(boundary)\r\n")
                body.appendString("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n")
                body.appendString("\(value)\r\n")
            }
        }

        let filename = "menu-image.jpg"

        let mimetype = "image/jpg"

        body.appendString("--\(boundary)\r\n")
        body.appendString("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(filePathKey!)\"; filename=\"\(filename)\"\r\n")
        body.appendString("Content-Type: \(mimetype)\r\n\r\n")
        body.append(imageDataKey)
        body.appendString("\r\n")



        body.appendString("--\(boundary)--\r\n")

        return body as Data
    }

}

//add appendString function
extension NSMutableData {

    func appendString(_ string: String) {
        let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)
        append(data!)
    }
}
```

My PHP page on my webserver looks like this:

```
<?php

 $user_id = $_POST["userId"];
 $target_dir = "../profPics/" . $user_id;

if(!file_exists($target_dir)) 
{  
    mkdir($target_dir, 0744, true);
} 

$target_dir = $target_dir . "/" . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_dir)) {
    echo json_encode([
        "message" => "The file ". basename( $_FILES["file"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.",
        "status" => "OK",
    "userId" => $user_id
    ]);

} else {

    echo json_encode([
        "message" => "Sorry, there was an error uploading your picture.",
        "status" => "Error",
            "userId" => $user_id
    ]);
}

?>
```

but then I try to upload an image and it prints out an error in the console saying:

```
{"message":"Sorry, there was an error uploading your picture.","status":"Error","userId":"6"}
```

It is correctly grabbing the userId from my saved login info, and is successfully posting it to the PHP page because the PHP page is returning it in the error (userId = 6.) I can't see anything wrong in the apache error.log. Can anyone see where I'm going wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Because of Yun CHEN's answer I was able to get a little further, but still cannot figure out where the 'file' comes into play in the PHP code. Is it something that is being defined in Swift? I've never worked with image uploads before and I'd like to know what's going on here. Thanks!

Comment: Still getting this error: `PHP Notice:  Undefined index: file in /var/www/html/scripts/imageUpload.php on line 11`

Comment: When I print out $_FILES in the error message, I get this: `{"message":"Sorry, there was an error uploading your picture.","status":"Error","userId":"6","dollarsignfiles:":{"file":{"name":"menu-image.jpg","type":"","tmp_name":"","error":1,"size":0}}}` There are no more errors in the apache log, but it is still not uploading.